# How to remove columns in a DataTable with certain characters in their name?

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-3.5

In my DataTable, I have columns which begin with #col_. How do I delete only these
columns from the table and leave the rest ?

I only know this snippet is needed - `table.Columns.RemoveAt(index);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var colsToRemove= (from DataColumn x in table.Columns
                          where x.ColumnName.StartsWith("#col_")
                          select x.ColumnName);

while (colsToRemove.Any())
    table.Columns.Remove(colsToRemove.First());
```